# PubNub - GetAllChannelGroups not working for some applications

Tags: channel, pubnub

We have 3 different free applications setup the same.  I run our application in all 3 environments.  However, when I call GetAllChannelGroups for all 3 of the applications only 1 of them returns results.  The other 2 always returns an empty list.  Is there a setting on the applications to allow this?

All 3 have Access Manager turned off.  Also, all 3 applications work properly.  It is just this one call to GetAllChannelGroups that does not work.

UPDATE: Just as a note.  I can take the pub/sub keys for the working environment and put them in the non-working environments and it works fine.  I get all the channel groups.  It has something to do with the applications themselves, but I see no settings that could resolve this or fix this.  We have also tried generating new keysets.

Answer (score 0):

## PubNub Stream Controller - Unlimited Channel Groups

On and after May 7, 2015, any PubNub keys that were created will allow unlimited Channel Groups on those keys. Keys created prior to that date were limited to 10K total *active* Channel Groups.

Keys with unlimited Channel Groups have two restricted that limited Channel Groups keys do not have:
 1. you can't use *namespaces*
 2. you can't list Channel Groups (get active channel groups) - but you can get channels in a given channel group

The issue is that you cannot see this *Unlimited Channel Groups* property in the Stream Controller add-on section for your keys in your [PubNub Admin Dashboard](https://admin.pubnub.com/#/login).

If you suspect this in your keys, please contact [PubNub Support](https://www.pubnub.com/support) with all the sub-keys you need verified and which way to configure them (unlimited or limited).

There is a knowledge base article that provides the above details: [Is there a limit to the number of channel groups in my PubNub key set?](https://www.pubnub.com/knowledge-base/discussion/540/is-there-a-limit-to-the-number-of-channel-groups-in-my-pubnub-key-set).